# What is the quiescent power dissipated by a TTL totem-pole output stage?

Tags: digital-logic, bjt, ttl, saturation

In High-Speed Digital Design by Johnson and Graham, the quiescent power of a TTL totem-pole is given as:
$$P_{quies} = \frac{0.4I_{sink} + 1.0I_{source}}{2}$$
I am fairly certain the 1.0 is a mistake and should be 1.4 instead. But my question has to do with the explanation for each coefficient.

First, the situation is considered where the lower transistor is turned ON. The voltage between seen at the output is the collector-emitter voltage of that lower transistor. They state that this is $$V_{LO} = 0.3 - 0.4 V$$
because this is the transistor's saturation voltage.
I agree that this is the voltage at the edge of saturation, but I don't see why V_LO   can't drop down to 0V?

Next, the situation is considered where the upper transistor is turned ON. They state that the voltage drop between the supply voltage V_CC and the output voltage is V_CC - V_HI. They state that this is $$V_{HI} = 1.4V$$ as it is the voltage drop V_BE + the voltage drop across the diode. Is this because V_B = V_CC if that transistor is on? But they also say that the upper transistor never goes into saturation because the base is never more positive than the collector. If V_B = V_CC, and there is a current flowing to the load, then won't there be a voltage drop across the resistor above the upper transistor, and hence V_C < V_CC and V_C < V_B, implying saturation?

Comment: The specification states that the worst-case output, when sinking 16 mA, is 400 mV. So that's where that number comes from, a specification, and it's just a worst-case guarantee not an average. But sure, the output voltage can be a lot less. Especially if the collector isn't being asked to sink 16 mA. It has about 2.5 mA of base current!!

Comment: @periblepsis I think that makes sense for V_LO. But then what about V_HI?

Comment: In the case I just mentioned, with 2.5 mA into the base there is also about 700 uA into the input base resistor from the supply, too. So already at 3.2 mA from the positive rail in that V_OL case. That's not exact. But it gets the idea. (The ground rail has to sink all that plus anything from what it is driving.) Does their equation account for this? (Not sure why the rest matters if this isn't right.)

Comment: I just [drew this up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9eu3c.png). It's the two output cases, ignoring the inputs. You can't really ignore the inputs, since they are required to show how current is sourced for the totem pole for the V_OL case. (The V_OH case doesn't really have to source much if any current from its rail if there's no load -- though with inputs it will have to sink some into ground.) Can you be a lot more specific by the addition of pictures, not just words?

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for the drawing. I edited it to display the situation as seen in the book: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Is1.png). I'm not sure what the various currents you gave in your previous comment have to do with this. But hopefully the image helps. I'm just trying to understand why 1.4V drop for output high and 0.4V drop for output low, although i think I understand the 0.4V now from your explanation in the first comment.

Comment: Okay. So I looked at the edited version you provided. If the output for V_OH (the term used in the [TTL specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTMfw.png)) is sourcing current into a load, then the current has to come through the upper transistor (Q1 on left side) and the diode. Both present some drop. Their spec gives you the worst case. I guess some of my confusion is that your question starts right out talking about **quiescent power**. (This got me thinking about the two unloaded cases for V_OH and V_OL. I don't have your book on-hand, unfortunately.)